# How can I eliminate interference between an overhanging countertop and a patio door opening?

Tags: kitchens, kitchen-counters, remodeling, countertops

I am in the process of remodeling the kitchen and the peninsula countertop coming into question:

[image]

It's right next to the patio door and there is only 4 inches space. The countertop is 3 feet wide.

[image]

[image]

That leaves me the question of whether to cut the countertop to make it thinner (28") or leave at 36" BUT do something creative on the overhang which will push over to the patio door (that right side is static and not moving, by the away, as the left door is sliding to right).

I have 4 options below:

1. Cut it and the line from patio trim moulding to line up with the countertop overhang edge.

[image]

2. Cut angle 45 degree. This gives illusion of the overhang is actually not "in the way"

[image]

3. Cut round

[image]

4. Cut square edges

[image]

I found #4 on the internet and it seems to be my favorite option.

Is there any advise or idea? Thanks.

Comment: I have the exact situation and am facing the exact choice. Incredibly hard to find “after” photos. I believe it is totally acceptable to have a bar top overhang beyond the wall, considering that there is a fixed slider “wall” there that you extending to. What did you decide to do? And do you have an after photo to post?

Comment: This question may not have gotten much response because it was mostly a matter of opinion. Did you arrive at a solution? Please either post and accept an answer or delete the question if it's abandoned.

Comment: Number 4, Number 4, Number 4.